# C++ Function that is Only Called Once

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project and to clean the code up in a big function, there is a segment of it that I think should be a separate function. But that separate function will only be used once, inside that bigger function. How should I treat it? Should it just be a normal `void` or is there a keyword I can throw before it? Could it be an `inline` function? I've heard of those but don't totally understand what they do. Thanks!

Comment: How is it implemented now? I mean how do they guarantee that that portion of the code only gets executed once as it is now?

Comment: There is no guarantee. I just do not plan on using it anywhere else. I define it right before the big function and call it in that same big function, and that's all.

Comment: Just having it in a separate function like you have it seems fine.  inline may be useful if it was a function that was called a lot.  It can save on call overhead. Read up on static functions if it is not already a class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick it in the same source (.cpp) file.  Place it within a `namespace {}` -- an anonymous namespace.  This guarantees it cannot be used/referred to outside of that source file, which both communucates to developers and compilers somewhat useful information.

`inline` all by itself is a bad idea due to potential odr violations (if another independent function with the same signature and name exists, bad things would happen).  For "famous" functions in header files the risk is mitigated somewhat.  `inline` once you put it in an anonymous namespace is innocuous, and may give amcompiler a hint that may be useful.  It probably does not matter.

Comment: I think this is what I was most looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @mats last I checked, no benefit, and minor penalty of not being able to use as a template parameter.  That, and `static` has so many meanings, why use it when there is something as good or better?

Answer (score 1):

inline is used for small and simple functions where you want to avoid the overhead of calling the function. It basically copies the code of the inline function inside your bigger function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/

Answer (score 0):

Granting the `run once` need is inside a namespace, I thus instantiate a `RunOnce` object and passing a lambda:

```
namespace mystuff {
    int somevars = 5;
    RunOnce initialize([&](){
       // do one-time initalization here
       somevars = 0;
    });
}
```

Where,

```
class RunOnce {
public:
    RunOnce(std::function<void(void)> init) {
        init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normally recommended to place a code with the single, clearly defined responsibility into dedicated function, even it that function is only called once. At least this is that I have seen in all books on topic.

This make the code more readable, maintainable and also you can now write a Unit test for the extracted function. If the function is unlikely to require dedicated testing (well covered with wider Unit tests, etc), you can still define it separately in the same file with `static` keyword, so it does not conflict with anything outside.